# rust: cannot move out of indexed context

Tags: rust

I'm very new to rust, and am starting to get the hang of the ownership system and such, but am still having some hangups. For exmaple, I have the following code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut t = vec![Box::new(4)];
    let mut o = t[0];
    *o = *o + 1;
    t[0] = o;
    println!("t[0]:{}", t[0]);
}
```

Which gives me the `cannot move out of indexed content` error for the line where I'm initializing `o`. I understand *why* this is happening, I think, but I can't figure out what I'm supposed to do instead to accomplish the same thing. This is a very simplified case, but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'd  encourage you to link to the other questions here on stack overflow that have the same error message and explain how your question differs from them.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you unmarked this as duplicate. The answer in that other thread doesn't seem to apply here, I've tried adding the `&` operator and that merely opens up a new can of errors. Moreover the other thread doesn't deal with re-setting the value in the vector, which I'm trying to do. You can see below the answers are very different.

Comment: Absolutely. [edit] your question to include a link to the other question and describe why it's not a duplicate. This will help future searchers understand why both questions need to exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `t[0]` is equivalent to either `*t.index(0)` or `*t.index_mut(0)`, based on context. These methods return an immutable reference and a mutable reference, respectively. The indexing operator automatically dereferences these.

Since you have a vector of `Box<i32>`, dereferencing is not valid, because that would try to move the value from the vector. But then, what do you put in the vector in its place?

Instead of trying to move the value, you need to use a reference to the value instead. Also, if you want to be able to add 1 to the value, you need a reference to the value, not a reference to the `Box`. You can do this by first dereferencing the box, then by taking a mutable reference to the result:

```
fn main() {
    let mut t = vec![Box::new(4)];
    {
        let o = &mut *t[0];
        *o = *o + 1;
    }
    println!("t[0]:{}", &t[0]);
}
```

I had to add a block here to make the mutable borrow end before the `println!`, otherwise the compiler complained with:

```
error: cannot borrow `t` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
```

Also, notice how we don't need to put the updated value back in the vector, because we changed the value in the vector directly by using a reference to it.

Comment: I think I understand, thanks for the help!